# What happens when Aang touches Ozai?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In the final confrontation between Aang and Ozai. Aang touches Ozai and their bodies become blue and orange color respectively, with blue/orange lasers shooting out of their eyes.

Can someone explain this phenomenon ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the limits of Energy-bending?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10331/what-are-the-limits-of-energy-bending) - as explained in the answer, it's their life energies battling.